# How to add Java 8+. Build with Maven in android project

Tags: java, android, maven

I have to Add Java 8+. Build with Maven in my Android Project, How to do it?

Actually, I have seen a project on github, So in order to use that project, I have to add the Prerequisites.

This is my **build.gradle** file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vincent.filepickersample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

These are the **dependencies**:

```
dependencies {
    //implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0'
    //implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':filepicker')
    //implementation files('libs/poi-3.12-android-a.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.dhatim:fastexcel-reader:0.10.2'
}
```

Comment: See the following documentation for details: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add proper compiler plugin configuration and required plugin in your *pom.xml* file:

```xml
<project>
  <packaging>apk</packaging><!-- or apklib --> 
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <!-- skipped other part of POM file -->
  <dependencies>
    <!-- here your compile or test scoped dependencies... -->
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version> <!-- use latest release -->
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

usage:

```sh
mvn install

mvn android:help

mvn android:run
mvn android:apk
mvn android:deploy
```

read more [here](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `pom.xml` file and use it normally, you just need to use the [Android Maven Plugin](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/) so that it compiles to an apk when you call a `mvn install`.

Comment: can you explain It more?

Comment: Make a regular pom, add the plugin linked above, then put in the dependencies you need. You can find them here: https://mvnrepository.com/